# Moving AJAX to server

Tags: ajax, rest, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

Right now I have HTML blocks that involve a script to call data from another DB (outside of concrete5) and I've been using XHTTP Posts to retrieve the data.

The problem: 
The scripts currently exist on the client side (e.g. you can see it by inspecting element) and I think it is being called from the client's device. Once I close down access to that external DB, this won't work anymore. I need these requests to come from my website and not the client.

The need: 
I know there is a way to move these requests to within Concrete5, so that concrete5 is making the requests and not the client. I'm just not sure how to go about doing this. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you make an AJAX request to your own server, and then from the server side make the request, and return the result to the client?

Comment: Is it being called multiple times, or just once when rendered?

Comment: @NicolaiDitlevKroghKrüger, only when rendered. So if the end user were to refresh a page that needs data, it should be called again. If the data changes without a refresh, no need to dynamically update.

Comment: Well, then for starters you can move the logic into the view() function of the block, and in that way get rid of exposing the logic to the user. If you could post a url or something so we could look more closely at your problem, we could make some better suggestion to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating an end point.. which is an address on your website that returns data when called.

so for example calling

```
www.domain.com/api/getusers{id}
```

Could return a JSON object for users.

A quick example.

in your application/bootstrap/app.php file you can add.

```
Route::register(
  '/api/getusers/{id}',
  'application\Controller\endpoints::getUsers'
);
```

Then you add a controller in application/controllers/endpoints.php

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Concrete\Core\Controller\Controller;
use \Concrete\Core\Http\Request;

class Endpoints extends Controller {

    /* Get all a Regions Expeditions */

    public function getUsers()
    {
      $id = Request::getInstance()->get('id');
      $userid = $th->sanitize($id);

            /* Do something with $id */

      echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
?>
```

More info can found here http://c5hub.com/learning/ajax-57-style/